# Variable Sharing

Tags: variables, swift, viewcontroller, sharing

I have an app in which, when a button is pressed on an original view, another view pops up. I want, basically, to be able to grab the text from a text field in the original view, and paste it onto a label in the new view. I've seen a bunch of Obj-c answers for this, but none for swift. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `prepareForSegue` for pass data from one view to another View.
Here is the code for that:

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var txt: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "goNext" {
        let nextView :nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController as nextViewController

        nextView.passedData = self.txt.text

        }
    }
}
```

**nextViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class nextViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
var passedData = String()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.lbl.text = self.passedData
    }
}
```

Here I created a sample project for you for more reference: https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/pass-Data-with-prepareForSegue-in-swift